# Problems with the estimation time of mixed logit models in R

Tags: r, performance, large-data, mixed-models, mlogit

I would like to estimate a mixed logit model for a group of 80,000 individuals and 1,200 alternatives in R. Packages like **gmnl** and **mlogit** take a significant time to estimate the model, even without including random parameters. The **mnlogit** package allows the estimation of models more efficiently and quickly. However, it does not allow to include random parameters. That is why I would like to know if there are packages (with available examples) designed for estimating Mixed Logit models with large datasets. So far I have found the **mixl** package. However, I have not found any examples available to help me understand how the package works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want frequentist methods, the usual suspects in R would be glmmTMB or lme4.

If you're willing to try Julia, then MixedModels.jl can handle logistic models that size. With JellyMe4.jl, you can even move the Julia fit back to R to use the R package ecosystem for examining the model (packages like car, sjtools, etc.).